# using std::find to find elements in vector of std::pair

Tags: c++, c++14, std, stdvector

Is there a way to use `std::find` within a `std::vector` of `std::pair`?
I want to go over the pairs' first members and search for the given value in the first members of the pairs only.
Of course, I can do it explicitly with a for loop, but can I do it in a more elegant way?
(I'm using c++14 if that matters)

Comment: `std::find_if` + lambda. Also you should provide [mcve]

Comment: With ranges library (C++20, or ranges-v3): `ranges::find(my_pairs, some_value, [](const auto& p) { return p.first; });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using `std::find_if`

```
include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<char, char>> v {
        std::make_pair('a', 'A'),
        std::make_pair('b', 'B'),
        std::make_pair('c', 'C')
    };
    auto it = std::find_if(
            v.begin(),
            v.end(),
            [](const auto& item) {
                return std::get<0>(item) == 'b';
            }
        );
    if (it != v.end()) {
        // found!
        std::cout << std::get<1>(*it) << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since OP mentioned using C++14, this could be cleaned up by using `auto` so that the long `iterator` type isn't specified, the comparator argument type is deduced, etc

Comment: @Human-Compiler, I considered that.  I actually prefer seeing the explicit type in reference documentation, so that I know what the type is.  I know, in the back of my mind, that in my own code, I could replace with `auto` if I wanted to reduce the amount of code, or if this needed to be implemented with templated types.  But since you suggest it, I'll make the edit.  Thanks.

Comment: I also prefer `const auto&`, especially as I already see that applied to `std::map`, and with missing `const` for key, it does an extra copy by pair :/

Answer (score 2):

I know you are using c++14, but one day (hopefully soon), you will be able to use c++20, which has range-ified algorithms that let you use projections.

So if you have a vector of pairs:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v { {1,2}, {2,3}, {3,4} };
```

you can `find` a `pair` whose `first` member is equal to a value like this:

```
auto f = std::ranges::find(v, 2, &std::pair<int, int>::first);
```

or you can `find_if` the `first` member of a `pair` satisfies some predicate, like this:

```
auto is_even = [](auto i) { return i % 2 == 0; };

auto f = std::ranges::find_if(v, is_even, &std::pair<int, int>::first);
```

This is about as elegant as it's likely to ever get, since the code doesn't really have any reducable complexity now.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YWvsTo).